# "WPF" creating storyboard from blend (xaml) and change target name from c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend, storyboard

i need to know how to change target name dynamicaly with same animation

Please find Below is my code of WPF for xaml and c# code

xaml code

```
<Storyboard x:Key="deepanshu"> 
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="gupta" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1"> 
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.641"/> 
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">     
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.689"/> 
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/> 
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-1"/> 
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1"> 
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.5"/> 
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

c# code

```
Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)FindResource("deepanshu"); 
// now how to change storyboard target name from image1 to image2
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like `SetTarget`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663141.aspx:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(sb.Children[0],"image2");
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help you well.

```
Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)FindResource("deepanshu"); 
Storyboard.SetTargetName(sb.Children[0],"image2");
Storyboard.SetTargetName(sb.Children[1],"image2");
Storyboard.SetTargetName(sb.Children[2],"image2");
sb.Begin();
```